# ListView with viewholder and checkbox state save

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

Simple shopping list app.
ListView (TextView + CheckBox with custom adapter. Tried to implement viewHolder pattern and completely lost. Am i right? Check my code. And also how to save checkbox state? I created massive, but dunno how to implement (Uncheck while scrolling bug).

ADAPTER:

```
public class ShopAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mainContex;
private ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems;
boolean[] checkBoxState = new boolean[shopItems.size()];

static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView textView;
}

public ShopAdapter(Context mainContex, ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems) {
    this.mainContex = mainContex;
    this.shopItems = shopItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return shopItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return shopItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ShopItem shopItem = shopItems.get(position);
    View item = convertView;
    if (item == null) {

        item = LayoutInflater.from(mainContex).inflate(R.layout.shoplist_item, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.doneCheckBox);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(shopItem.getDescription());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(shopItem.isDone());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    shopItem.setDone(true);
                    viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.done_text_color));
                } else {
                    shopItem.setDone(false);
                    viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.secondary_text));
                }
            }
        });
        item.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(shopItems.get(position));
    } else {
        item = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) item.getTag()).checkBox.setTag(shopItems.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
    holder.textView.setText(shopItems.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(shopItems.get(position).isDone());
    return item;
}
```

}

ITEM:

```
public class ShopItem {

private String description;
private boolean done;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public boolean isDone() {
    return done;
}

public void setDone(boolean done) {
    this.done = done;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper implementation of your code-

```
    private static class ViewHolder {
                CheckBox checkBox;
                TextView textView;
            }

            public ShopAdapter(Context mainContex, ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems) {
                this.mainContex = mainContex;
                this.shopItems = shopItems;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return shopItems.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return shopItems.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ShopItem shopItem = shopItems.get(position);
                ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) { 
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoplist_item, null);

                    viewHolder.textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
                    viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.doneCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }
             else 
           {                
          viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }
viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(shopItems.get(position));
                    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                shopItem.setDone(true);
                                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.done_text_color));
                            } else {
                                shopItem.setDone(false);
                                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.secondary_text));
                            }
                        }
                    });




                viewHolder.textView.setText(shopItem.getDescription());
               viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(shopItem.isDone());
                   return convertView;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use **SparseBooleanArray**

**Try below code**

```
public class ShopAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mainContex;
private ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems;
boolean[] checkBoxState = new boolean[shopItems.size()];
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

static class ViewHolder {
CheckBox checkBox;
TextView textView;
}

public ShopAdapter(Context mainContex, ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems) {
this.mainContex = mainContex;
this.shopItems = shopItems;
mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return shopItems.size();
}


 @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return shopItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ShopItem shopItem = shopItems.get(position);
View item = convertView;
if (item == null) {

    item = LayoutInflater.from(mainContex).inflate(R.layout.shoplist_item, null);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
    viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.doneCheckBox);

   if(mSelectedItemsIds.get(position)){
         shopItem.setDone(true);
         viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources().getColor(R.color.done_text_color));
    } else{
        shopItem.setDone(false);      
          viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources().getColor(R.color.secondary_text));
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setText(shopItem.getDescription());
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(shopItem.isDone());
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
                shopItem.setDone(true);
                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.done_text_color));
            } else {
                mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
                shopItem.setDone(false);
                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.secondary_text));
            }
        }
    });
    item.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(shopItems.get(position));
} else {
    item = convertView;
    ((ViewHolder) item.getTag()).checkBox.setTag(shopItems.get(position));
}
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
holder.textView.setText(shopItems.get(position).getDescription());
holder.checkBox.setChecked(shopItems.get(position).isDone());
return item;
}

}
```