# Android get value of checkbox when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-checkbox

Im new in developing an android applications. I have encounter a certain problem wherein i need to get the value of the checkbox when i click a button. i have put it in a listview in simplecursoradapter. my problem is that when the data is too many. the checkbox only gets one checkbox. how will i get other values from other checkboxes when i only have 1 checkbox in my xml file.

Thank you for your help.

```
btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RetailerDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new RetailerDatabaseHelper(TemplateActivity.this);
            final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); //For further investigation!
            Cursor c10 = db.query("Retailer", new String[]{"_id", "name", "validity"}, null, null, "name", null, null, null);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(TemplateActivity.this, R.layout.custom_dialog_box, c10, new String[]{"name","validity"}, new int[]{R.id.checkBox1, R.id.number}, 0);
            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);

            if(cb.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: use viewholder to keep track of checkboxes in each row

Comment: Hello, how to use viewholder?

Comment: check this out, this is a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252602/listview-with-viewholder-and-checkbox-state-save

Comment: Can i use this when my datas are coming from database? cause im using simplecursoradapter

Comment: you should use this always, A ViewHolder describes an item view and metadata about its place

Comment: Ohhh. alright im gonna try this one.

Comment: One more thing, ill just call the listadapter in my main activity?

Comment: you need to make adapter class for that

Comment: yes i will create the adapter class and then i will call it in main activity?

Comment: you just need to set adapter on your listview. as you are doing it now

Comment: i still cant do it :(

Comment: you need to go through some tutorials first, check this out http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php and http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-checkbox-example/